# Change font color based on Date using VBA in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I used the code from this [link](https://www.exceltip.com/general-topics-in-vba/change-font-color-based-on-date-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html) to change colors of the cell if the date was less than today's date.
It was working perfectly except it was changing colors for all the cells and not just the range I mentioned. The functionality I wanted to implement is real time color change of cells whenever the date is changed.

```
Sub SetColor()

If IsDate(ActiveCell.Value) And ActiveCell.Value < Date Then
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
Else
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 228, 240)
End If

End Sub

Sub ResetColor()

'Declaring variables
Dim Rng, Source As Range
Dim IntRow As Integer, IntCol As Integer

'Specifying all the cells as source range
Set Source = Range("E2:E50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)

'Looping through all the cells
For Each Rng In Source
    'Checking whether cell contains a value
    If Not IsEmpty(Rng) Then
        'Checking whether cell contain value of date data type
        If IsDate(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Select
            
            'Assigning Red color if value is less than today date
            If DateValue(Rng.Value) < Date Then
                ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Else
                ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 228, 240)
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next Rng

End Sub

    

'Insert below code in ThisWorkbook module

Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

With Worksheets("Main")

    'Event fired on entry to worksheet
    .OnEntry = "SetColor"
    'Event fired on sheet activation
    .OnSheetActivate = "ResetColor"
    
End With

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    
With Worksheets("Main")
    .OnEntry = ""
    .OnSheetActivate = ""
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you use *conditional formatting*?

Comment: What range do you think "you mentioned"? Can you write here what address do you think that your code should process? I mean, the address range you want to be processed. In fact, you can simple use Contional Formatting, as recommended above, but it would be good to understand the code you try using, too... `Set Source = Range("E2:E50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)` returns a single cell. The last one (**last row of the last column**). Do you want processing the range starting from E2 to the last cell in column E:E?

Comment: I tried conditional formatting but with that I wasn't able to apply the Value < Date rule for all the cells. And @FaneDuru E2:E50 is the range I want to work on. Like 1st row is title, from 2nd row to 50th of E it should change colors

Comment: In Conditional Formatting you should use Address of the first cell in the range < Today() (`"=E2<Today()"`).. If that is the range you need to process, just follow my answer suggestion in defining of the `Source` range. It will process as many cells there are in column E:E, starting from E2. If you want processing only E2:E50, then use `Set Source = Range("E2:E50")`

Answer (score 0):

You do not answer the clarification question...

Supposing that you intend to process the range **"E2" up to the last cell in column "E:E"**, please try replacing:

```
Set Source = Range("E2:E50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
```

with:

```
Set Source = Range("E2:E" & Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row)
```

If not this is what you intend doing, I will delete my answer but please, try answering the clarification question, or try better explain what range do you wont your code to process.

Comment: I will keep increasing the range, it's just that the column E should change colors when the date is changed. With conditional formatting, it compares only the  first date and highlights the whole column as red. If I use conditional formatting, I'll have to make new rule for every row that's why I tried doing it with VBA

Comment: @Yash Gandhi You shouldn't make rule for every row. I gave that formula to be written **after selecting all range to be conditional formatted, starting from "E2"**. But did the above code change suggestion solve your problem?

Comment: The above code didn't help. It still highlighted cells in other columns whose date is less than today. While for conditional formatting, I did try and select the whole column and put this in the rule " =$E$2:$E$50<Today() " It only compared the first date and highlighted the whole column till E50

Comment: @Yash Gandhi It looks we are talking different languages... I am not referring to English. If you exactly  copied the code line I posted, it should process only that column. Unless, you conditional formatted all the range by mistake. And I suggested to only select all the range, but the formula to be `=E2<Today()`. Do you understand the signification of absolute and relative addresses? If you use `$E$2` the address will not be incremented, because it is an absolute reference. If you are able to follow my suggestion exactly, it should work. If not, I whish you a good and successful day, anyhow!

Comment: I just put "E2:E10" instead of "$" in Conditional formatting in Excel and disabled the macros. It is working perfectly. Thank you so much and I apologize for the miscommunication.

Comment: @Yash Gandhi OK. But don't you want to understand why your code does not run as you need? Do you want a fish or learn fishing...?

Comment: I'd like to and I did try understanding it on my own from those sites but I wasn't quite successful.

Comment: Then create a new testing sheet, put the range you need to process in column E:E, make the replacing I recommended above and see what happens. Before that, do the next: Put a code line immediately after the `Source` definition **like it is**. `MsgBox Source.Address`. You will obtain the address of the last cell (unique cell). Then change the line as I recommended above and see what the message returns...

Comment: With the existing line the message box read "$F$50" and with the line you suggested it said "$E$2:$E$10" and there were only 9 records till E10, rest was blank till 50

Comment: So, it is correct. Doesn't the code do what you need using the modified line?

Comment: That's what. The address does say till $E$10 but when I modify a date from other columns suppose G, H, or I it gets highlighted to red. The code I provided is the same one I'm using without any changes btw

Comment: This cannot be possible. Did you use a new sheet as I said? If yes, did yo copy all the sheet, not only the range in E:E? Otherwise, what .'other cumns' are involved?

Comment: Yes, I made a new sheet copied everything from the previous sheet column by column and also copy pasted the same code with your changes. This is kind of a document where the dates highlighted to red refers that the particular task is to be finished on priority while the other dates could be the task completed by that person on that date which could be before/after the reference date ( Column E )

Comment: @Yash Gandhi You did it wrong! Why do you think I recommended to work in a new sheet? Only to be sure that you do not have some conditional formatting put in the rest of the sheet by mistake. If you wont to copy everything, copy in a different way. Select all what you want copying and then **right click and choose PasteSpecial -> paste As Value**.  You must be sure that **you do not copy the format, too**. Just copying, the format is also moved on the new sheet and you did not solve anything...l

Comment: I did exactly as you said actually. Copied everything so that nothing from that sheet comes here. It looked pretty basic without any colors and all so I'm positive I did it right. But I did it again just to confirm and then put the code in vba and its the same thing all over. I think there's a problem in the sub SetColor. Like any cell I select it will make it red if the date is < today

Comment: @Yash Gandhi: If you did not copy using Copy -> PasteSpecial (Value), the conditional formatted has been copied, too. You do not see anything if the range does not have a date < today. But, in order to check that, copy the sheet as you did **in a new one**, **do not run the code** and try changing other columns date value. How does it behave? If it is OK, run the code and do the same check after...

Comment: I did it exactly like you have mentioned here. Copied it normally without any formats, checked if the dates are getting changes ( which they weren't ) then I copied the code, ran it and then again it was like before. Highlighting every date in the sheet and the message box still displayed "$E$10"

Comment: @Yash Gandhi: If the message displaies "$E$10" this only means that you do not understand what you are doing, no offence... If you adapted the code as I suggested, you should receive "$E$2:$E$10", **as you confirmed in a comment above**. If you are not able to do such a simple task, I am afraid that I am wasting my time. I wish you a good day!

Comment: My bad, it indeed shows "$E$2:$E$10" and you are right about me not knowing what I am doing here. I guess it is okay if I don't solve it using VBA since it's anyway done with conditional formatting. Thanks for your time though.